# Display order for grails One to Many relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes as following

```
class Quiz {
    String name
    String description
    int duration
    User user
    int points
    static hasMany = [questions:Question]
}
```

and

```
class Question {
    String question
    String questionType
    int points  
    String option_1
    String option_2
    String option_3
    String option_4
    boolean isOption_1_Correct
    boolean isOption_2_Correct
    boolean isOption_3_Correct
    boolean isOption_4_Correct
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

static hasMany = [questions:Question] in Quiz class has made my life a lot easier. I also understand it will be able to use convenience methods like addTo and removeFrom. Only query I have is that I want users to be able to define display order for the questions. Is there an easier way to do this or do I have to create a mapping class like following?

```
class QuestionInQuiz {
    Quiz quiz
    Question question
    int displayOder
    static constraints = {
        question unique:['quiz']
    }
}
```

It will be great if i can somehow avoid using this mapping class and keep my code simpler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
List questions
```

to your `Quiz` class (in addition to the `hasMany`) then GORM will use a `List` for the association rather than the default unordered `Set`.  The [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `position` property to `Question` class. You should add a `mapping` static closure to `Quiz` class:

```
static mapping = {
    questions sort:'position'
}
```

Then you should to link the `Question` with the `Quiz` -> `belongsTo = [user: User, quiz: Quiz]`

I believe that you can to refine your model creating a `Option` class and an enumeration `QuestionType` What happen if tomorrow you have a question with 5 or 6 options? You want to rewrite, retest, recompile and redeploy your code?

Or your can to implement the `Comparable` interface in Question and to create a `SortedSet` of questions

```
class Quiz {
    SortedSet questions
    String name
    String description
    int duration
    User user
    int points
    static hasMany = [questions:Question]
}

class Question implements Comparable<Question> {
    String question
    String questionType
    int points  
    int position
    String option_1
    String option_2
    String option_3
    String option_4
    boolean isOption_1_Correct
    boolean isOption_2_Correct
    boolean isOption_3_Correct
    boolean isOption_4_Correct
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user:User]

    int CompareTo(obj){
        position <=> obj.position
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I tried to create options Class but there was just too much work to make it happen:) I am ready to add upto 20 options if need be. The biggest issue I have against Options class is to create options at the same time of creating the question itself rather then one after another!

Comment: What should I do if I get  this error 'No owner defined between domain classes [class com.easytha.Question] and [class com.easytha.Quiz] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = com.easytha.Quiz'?

Comment: You should to edit `static belongsTo = [user:User, quiz: Quiz]` in `Question` class

Comment: but that would make a question belong to one and only one Quiz, won't it?

Comment: or atleast the order won't be per quiz?